# How can I inject an Angular controller into my unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm really hoping this is a trivial issue.  Yes, I have RTFM. I'm actually using the Angular documented way to inject a controller, but for some reason my controller is not defined. The main difference here is that I'm used to working on single module apps and this time I have a multi module app. I wouldn't think it would make a difference, but there you go. Instead of a lengthy description, I'll get straight to the code:

Using Angular 1.2.16

Unit Test Framework: Jasmine

app.js

```
 angular.module('OBB', [
  // Native AngularJS DI
  'ngResource', 'ngCookies', 

  // bunch of modules
  ...

  // OBB Page Modules
  'OBB.home', 'OBB.buckets', 'OBB.company', 'OBB.advSearch', 'OBB.users'
])
```

So, I'm trying to test a controller in the OBB.home module.

home.js

```
angular.module('OBB.home', ['ui.router'])
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$log', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', 'AUTH_EVENTS',  
  function HomeCtrl ($log, $rootScope, $scope, $state, AUTH_EVENTS) {
    $scope.signInFormData = {
      email: null, password: null
    };
    //more code...
}]);
```

home.spec.js

```
describe('Unit Home Controllers: ', function () {

  var homeController, scope;

  beforeEach(module('OBB.home'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, $controller) {
      scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      homeController = $controller('HomeCtrl', {
        $rootScope: _$rootScope_,
        $scope: scope,
        $log: {},
        $state: {},
        AUTH_EVENTS: {},
      });
    }));

  it('Home Controller is correctly instantiated', inject(function () {
    expect(scope).toBeDefined();  // Pass
    expect(scope.signInFormData).toBeDefined();  // Fails
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock/load your dependencies.

```
describe('Unit Home Controllers: ', function () {

  var homeController, scope;

  beforeEach(module('OBB.home'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, $controller) {
      scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      homeController = $controller('HomeCtrl', {
        $rootScope: _$rootScope_,
        $scope: scope,
        $log: {},  //You will have to add methods as needed
        $state: {},
        AUTH_EVENTS: {}
      });
    }));

  it('Home Controller is correctly instantiated', inject(function () {
    expect(scope).toBeDefined();  // Fails
    expect(scope.signInFormData).toBeDefined();  // Fails
  }));
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Even after making sure the function param lists matched, I'm still getting an undefined controller.  What's frustrating the most is that there's no error messages even giving me a hint of what could be wrong.  It's just undefined.  I'm not sure if there's a nested error because the module has dependent services as well.  I'm going to go through the controller and start commenting out everything and slowly open it up to see if that helps.